# How to handle click event on tab item of TabNavigator in React Native App using react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, tabnavigator, ex-navigation

I am programming React Native App. I am using react-navigation for navigating screens.

I have 2 Stack Navigators, they are stayed in a Tab Navigator. I want handle click event when I press tab item on TabBar to refresh its view.

```js
export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: ScreenHome},
  Detail: {screen: ScreenDetail}
})
export const UserStack = StackNavigator({
  User: {screen: ScreenUser}
})
export const Tabbar = TabNavigator({
  HomeTab: {
    screen: HomeStack,
  },
  UserTab: {
    screen: UserStack,
  }   
}, {
  tabBarComponent: ({ jumpToIndex, ...props}) => (
       <TabBarBottom
          {...props}
          jumpToIndex={(index) => {
            if(props.navigation.state.index === index) {
            props.navigation.clickButton(); //----> pass props params (code processes)
          }
          else {
            jumpToIndex(index);
          }
        }
      }
    />
   ),
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
});
class TabClass extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.clickButton = this.clickButton.bind(this)
  }
  clickButton(){
    console.log('click button')
  }
  render (){
    return (
      <Tabbar  clickButton={()=> this.clickButton()}/>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to pass clickButton() function from TabClass Component to the code which processes event click tab bar. When if(props.navigation.state.index === index), I want it will call clickButton(). I try it but it doesn't work. 
Is there any way to solve my matter?

I tried onNavigationStateChange(prevState, currentState).

```js
class TabClass extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.clickButton = this.clickButton.bind(this)
  }
  clickButton(){
    console.log('click button')
  }
  _handleNavagationStateChange(prevState, currentState){
    console.log('handle navigation state change')
  }
  render (){
    return (
        <Tabbar onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
          this._handleNavagationStateChange(prevState, currentState)
        }}
        clickButton={()=> this.clickButton()}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

However, _handleNavagationStateChange(prevState, currentState) only run when navigation state changes (for examples, if I stay at HomeTab, I click User Tab Item, this function will run; if I stay at HomeTab, I click Home Tab Item, this function will not run).

Is there any way to handle click event on tab item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code following when customize the event touch of TabBar:

```js
 import { TabBarBottom, TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

 export const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeViewContainer },
    Search: { screen: SearchViewContainer },
 }, {
   tabBarComponent: ({ jumpToIndex, ...props, navigation }) => (
     <TabBarBottom
      {...props}
             jumpToIndex = { tabIndex => {
             const currentIndex = navigation.state.index;

             if (tabIndex == 1) {
             // do some thing. Call Native Live Stream Record
             } else {
                jumpToIndex(tabIndex);
             }
             console.log('Select tab: ', tabIndex);
         }}
        />),
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

according to the newest documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbarlabel), you can use `navigationOptions: {navigationOptions: () => doWhatever()}` to handle tab bar taps.

Answer (score 2):

From the [react-navigation 4.x docs](https://eactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress), you can override `tabBarOnPress` within `navigationOptions`:

```
tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
  defaultHandler(); // Call the default handler to actually switch tabs
  // do extra stuff here
},
```

Answer (score 2):

An updated answer for v6:

**To take an action (other than/in addition to the built-in navigation) on tab press, you can set a listener for `tabPress` events on the navigator via `screenListeners`, or screen via `listeners`.**

For our app, the following setup worked, where a `screenListener` is set for `tabPress` events, which then calls an `analyticsEvent` function:

```js
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

  return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={Screens.Home}
        screenListeners={({route}) => ({ // listener receives navigation, route
          tabPress: () => {
            analyticsEvent(route);
          },
        })}>
        // etc.
    )
```

Navigation proceeds as usual, but an analytics event is fired as well.

See the ["Navigation Events" section of the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/) for more details.

(According to the docs, you could also set this on the `<Tab.Screen>` level via the `listeners` prop, but that did not work for me, though I didn't debug much.)